# Does iOS have a budget for remote push notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone know if iOS has a budget for remote push notifications?

That is, if an app or device receives too many remote push notifications in a day, is the app or device "cut off" or limited in some way for the remainder of the day?

I know that the Apple Watch has a budget for complication updates.  I also know that there is a budget for the number of background refreshes an iOS app can request during a day.  This varies depending on the iOS's determination of that app's usage patterns, being a "good citizen", battery life, etc.

If there is a budget for remote push notifications, is it at the app level, or device level?  Is there any way to know when it has been exhausted?

The reason for the inquiry is that I'm considering forcing regular background activity in an app via remote push notifications.  Not ideal, but more reliable than background refresh intervals.

Thanks for any help / insight you can provide.

Comment: Have you done any digging to see if this use of push notifications is kosher? Seems like something that could get caught in the app approval filter.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sending multiple notifications to the same device within a short period of time, the push service will send only the last one. For that reason, I do not recommend to use the push notification to trigger the method or background activity.

Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) does not warranty that push notifications are arrived all the time, it is risky!